# Changing variable values in if statement not working discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make a command so that you can get detailed information on what a command can do. I made it so that theircommand is the word after c!command. I tested it multiple times and it works and print out the exact words. Im making it so that if the word after c!command is credits, then it will set the imag and info variables to the following url and text. For some reason, I dont think it considered theircommand = credits, because the imag variable was still 'joe'. I got this error:

```
Scheme "joe" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ("https", "http").
```

My code:

```
       theircommande = message.content
       theircommand = theircommande.replace('c!command','')
       await message.channel.send(theircommand)
       info = 'joe'
       imag = 'joe'
       if theircommand == 'credits':
         imag = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1048897561253122120/1055079211297165413/image.png'
         info = 'List of people who have helped or currently helping the Chappers bot, and credits to helpful websites used for some specific commands.'
       comme=discord.Embed(title=theircommand,description=info,color=0x00aaff)
       comme.set_image(url=imag)
       await message.channel.send(embed=comme)
```

Please tell me whats wrong with the code that makes the if statement not work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the way you replace the `c!command` with nothing may be leaving an extra space character before the `credits`, so the string would be  `credits` (with a space in front).

To fix this, you could change your replace statement from

```py
theircommand = theircommande.replace('c!command','')
```

to

```py
theircommand = theircommande.replace('c!command ','')
```

(notice the extra space after `c!command`)

or alternatively you can change the way you're checking `theircommand` from:

```py
if theircommand == 'credits':
```

to

```py
if theircommand.strip() == 'credits':
```

I can't tell if this is the exact issue, as your question is a bit vague, however this is my best guess as to what is happening. Hope this helps!

Comment: I will test it out, and I apologize if my question was quite vague. Edit: It works now, I changed it to replace.c!command ','' and now it works. Thank you.